# How to present UIViewController on top of current view controller with smaller height

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to present a UIViewController on top of the current view controller and set it's height to ~80% of the screen size. I've got the first part:

```
let additionalVC = ChartsViewController(currentSelection)
additionalVC = .overCurrentContext
present(additionalVC, animated: true)
```

I tried setting the `self.view.frame` inside my `ChartsVC` in viewDidLoad and couple of different things but it is always presented in the full screen mode.

That's what I want to achieve:

- blueVC - currentVC
- redVC - `ChartsVC` - VC on top of the current VC with ~80% of the original height

[image]

btw I'm doing everything programmatically, no xib and `UIStoryboard`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of ways to achieve this.

You could use a 3rd party framework (http://transitiontreasury.com/) or the way I would do this.

Present the newVC where a transition = model over current context

ensure the newVC.views background color is clear

add another view where origin.y is the distance between the top and the desired gap. This is the view where all your objects will sit on.

If you need a coding example let me know, but its a pretty simple solution and looking at your code your 80% there.

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

Implement a custom `UIPresentationController`.  To use a custom view size, you only need to override a single property.

This code will simply inset the presented view controller by 50x100 pts:

```
class MyPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

    // Inset by 50 x 100
    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        return self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 50, dy: 100)
    }

}
```

To darken the presenting view controller, override `presentationTransitionWillBegin()` and `dismissalTransitionWillBegin()` to insert a shading view and animate it into view:

```
class MyPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        return self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 50, dy: 100)
    }

    let shadeView = UIView()

    override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        self.shadeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.shadeView.alpha = 0

        // Insert the shade view above the presenting view controller
        self.shadeView.frame = self.presentingViewController.view.frame
        self.containerView?.insertSubview(shadeView, 
            aboveSubview: self.presentingViewController.view)

        // Animate it into view
        self.presentingViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            self.shadeView.alpha = 0.3
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
        self.presentingViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            self.shadeView.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

To use your custom presentation controller, set the `modalPresentationStyle` and `transitioningDelegate`:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

  // 
  // Your code
  //
  func presentCharts() {
    let additionalVC = ChartsViewController(currentSelection)
    additionalVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    additionalVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    self.present(additionalVC, animated: true)
  }

  //
  // UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol
  //
  func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                              presenting: UIViewController?,
                              source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {

    return MyPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented,
                                    presenting: presenting)

  }
}
```

Comment: In `presentationTransitionWillBegin()` there will be an animation issue that occurs if `UIAccessibility.prefersCrossFadeTransitions` is true. The workaround is to put the alpha value in the backgroundColor and let the alpha of the view go to 1 instead. (This appears to be due to an iOS bug.)

Answer (score 1):

In IOS 13 and Xcode 11, you can present ViewController with modalPresentationStyle = .automatic

Answer (score 0):

Take Two `ViewController`.First `view controller` have a `button` and the button action name is `clicked`.The target is to clicking the `button` we want to add `secondVC` as a child of first `view controller` and show `secondVC` 80% of the first `view controller`.again click button we remove `secondVC` from `first view controller`. below is the code for `click button action`.

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if !isshown{
        isshown = true

        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        let height = view.frame.height
        let width  = view.frame.width
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100 , width: width, height: height - 100)
        }, completion: { (result) in
            // do what you want to do
        })

    }else{
        isshown = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                       animations: { () -> Void in
                        var frame = self.vc.view.frame
                        frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY
                        self.vc.view.frame = frame

        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            self.vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.vc.removeFromParentViewController()
        })
    }

}
```

here `vc` is a reference of `secondVC`.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! secondVC
```

change below piece of code to get whatever **percentage** you want.

```
self.vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100 , width: width, height: height - 100)
```